# Cannot use refresh token to obtain new access token and refresh token in Identity Server 3 implementation

Tags: identityserver3, thinktecture-ident-server

I've been playing around with Thinktecture's identity server and now I have some problems trying to reach the refresh token endpoint.

What I have is few clients configured like this:

**Authorization code flow client:**

new Client

```
{
    ClientId = "tripgalleryauthcode",
    ClientName = "Trip Gallery (Authorization Code)",
    Flow = Flows.AuthorizationCode, 
    AllowAccessToAllScopes = true,
    RequireConsent = false,

    RedirectUris = new List<string>
    {
        "redirecturi"
    },           

     ClientSecrets = new List<Secret>()
    {
        new Secret("somesecret".Sha256())
    }                    
}
```

**Hybrid flow client:**

```
new Client 
{
    ClientId = "tripgalleryhybrid",
    ClientName = "Tripgalleryhybrid (Hybrid)",
    Flow = Flows.Hybrid, 
    AllowAccessToAllScopes = true,

    RequireConsent = false,

    IdentityTokenLifetime = 10,
    AccessTokenLifetime = 120,

    // redirect = URI of the MVC application
    RedirectUris = new List<string>
    {
        "redirecturi"
    },

    // Needed when requesting refresh tokens
    ClientSecrets = new List<Secret>()
    {
        new Secret("somesecret".Sha256())
    },
    PostLogoutRedirectUris = new List<string>()
    {
        "postlogouturi"
    }
}
```

What I do is, I have ASP.NET MVC client which uses the hybrid flow. After the authentication I receive access token, refresh token and some other stuff.

What I am trying to do is to test the refresh token endpoint. The way I prepare my request is as follows:

I make a **POST** request to: **/identity/connect/revocation** 
In the headers of the request I have:

- Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
- Authorization: Basic dHJpcGdhbGxlcnlhdXRoY29kZTpteXJhbmRvbWNsaWVudHNlY3JldA==(**This is base64 encoded clientid:clientsecret that are my Authorization Code ones**)

In the request body I have: **token=0a24f80dcc97a56ede0e7c04563a3493&token_type_hint=refresh_token**

The token is the one that came after my authentication trough the hybrid client.

When I fire the request it returns Http 200. But no content is returned back. When I go the Identity Server logs this is what I see:

```
SnapshotHelper::TakeSnapshotTimerCallback
SnapshotHelper::TakeSnapshotInternal - no new files in CodeGen
w3wp.exe Warning: 0 : 2016-11-13 13:54:11.557 +00:00 [Warning] AuthorizationCodeStore not configured - falling back to InMemory
w3wp.exe Warning: 0 : 2016-11-13 13:54:11.620 +00:00 [Warning] TokenHandleStore not configured - falling back to InMemory
w3wp.exe Warning: 0 : 2016-11-13 13:54:11.620 +00:00 [Warning] ConsentStore not configured - falling back to InMemory
w3wp.exe Warning: 0 : 2016-11-13 13:54:11.620 +00:00 [Warning] RefreshTokenStore not configured - falling back to InMemory
w3wp.exe Information: 0 : 2016-11-13 13:54:12.356 +00:00 [Information] Start token revocation request
w3wp.exe Information: 0 : 2016-11-13 13:54:12.401 +00:00 [Information] Client secret id found: "tripgalleryauthcode"
w3wp.exe Information: 0 : 2016-11-13 13:54:12.401 +00:00 [Information] Client validation success
w3wp.exe Information: 0 : 2016-11-13 13:54:12.401 +00:00 [Information] End token revocation request
```

What I really expected to get at least new access and refresh tokens but nothing. I guess I am really missing something in the configuration of my clients so I would be very happy if you could help me.

**EDIT:**

I changed the endpoint to: **/identity/connect/token** and also changed the request body to: 
**grant_type=refresh_token&token=635c7cbcfa1c0417b6d574ade388c0d8&token_type_hint=refresh_token** but still no success. Now my Identity server log says:

```
SnapshotHelper::TakeSnapshotTimerCallback
SnapshotHelper::TakeSnapshotInternal - no new files in CodeGen
SnapshotHelper::TakeSnapshot time since last: 00:19:59.9992231
w3wp.exe Information: 0 : 2016-11-13 20:40:33.406 +00:00 [Information] Start token request
w3wp.exe Information: 0 : 2016-11-13 20:40:33.406 +00:00 [Information] Client secret id found: "tripgalleryauthcode"
w3wp.exe Information: 0 : 2016-11-13 20:40:33.406 +00:00 [Information] Client validation success
w3wp.exe Information: 0 : 2016-11-13 20:40:33.406 +00:00 [Information] Start token request validation
w3wp.exe Information: 0 : 2016-11-13 20:40:33.406 +00:00 [Information] Start validation of refresh token request
w3wp.exe Error: 0 : 2016-11-13 20:40:33.406 +00:00 [Error] "Refresh token is missing"
 "{
  \"ClientId\": \"tripgalleryauthcode\",
  \"ClientName\": \"Trip Gallery (Authorization Code)\",
  \"GrantType\": \"refresh_token\",
  \"Raw\": {
    \"grant_type\": \"refresh_token\",
    \"token\": \"635c7cbcfa1c0417b6d574ade388c0d8\",
    \"token_type_hint\": \"refresh_token\"
  }
}"
w3wp.exe Information: 0 : 2016-11-13 20:40:33.406 +00:00 [Information] End token request
w3wp.exe Information: 0 : 2016-11-13 20:40:33.406 +00:00 [Information] Returning error: invalid_request
```

**SECOND EDIT:**

Based on the documentation posted here: [Token Endpoint](https://identityserver.github.io/Documentation/docsv2/endpoints/token.html) and what's inside of it here: [TokenRequest](http://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#TokenRequest) and many more resources related to that I came to this request:

[image]

which I believe is the correct one. Unfortunatelly I am still getting HTTP 400 from by identity server with an error that says: **error=invalid_grant**. This makes me think that most likely I have to make some more configuration on my client. In some of the examples on the internet I can see the usage of: **AbsoluteRefreshTokenLifetime, SlidingRefreshTokenLifetime, RefreshTokenUsage, RefreshTokenExpiration** when configuring the client. Can you please give me at least a direction to dig into?

**SOLUTION:**

What worked for me was to add these options to the client:
// refresh token options

```
AccessTokenType = AccessTokenType.Jwt,
AccessTokenLifetime = 3600,
RefreshTokenUsage = TokenUsage.ReUse,
RefreshTokenExpiration = TokenExpiration.Absolute,
AbsoluteRefreshTokenLifetime = 1296000
```

Comment: Thanks, your solution helps me solve my issue.

Answer (score 2):

You're using the revocation endpoint, which allows you to destroy (aka "revoke") a token. To use the refresh token to get a new access token, you want the token endpoint with the grant_type=refresh_token, as covered in the docs: https://identityserver.github.io/Documentation/docsv2/endpoints/token.html

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! I just changed the endpoint and modified the POST body a little bit bust I still get no valuable response. I have edited my post and you can see that now I am getting invalid_request.

Comment: I really did but still don't know why it is not working. I think my edit has to do the work. I tried with such body: grant_type=refresh_token&refresh_token=23988f082daf7bd88a3facabe54fc8d7 and still nothing. I tried to add client id and client secret both on headers and post body but still the same. There must be a more general error here except the one for the endpoint address.

Comment: I made another edit to my post which I believe is the correct way to make a call to the token endpoint. I really read all of the documentation couple of times and there's nothing else I can think of. Could you at least point me a direction to dig into?